# how to move cursor to previous intbox after hitting backspace in zk

Tags: zk

I am trying to move the cursor within the textbox in zk.

I made this code so if we are at second intbox and enter a number the control/cursor will move to the third intbox.

Now what I want to achieve is suppose we are at intbox 4 and we hit backspace the cursor/control should move to third intbox.

Can someone help me on this?

```
<zk>
<hbox>
<intbox id="A"  onChanging="B.focus();" />
<intbox id="B" onChanging="C.focus();" />
<intbox id="C" onChanging="D.focus();" />
<intbox id="D" onChanging="A.focus();" />
</hbox>
</zk>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you read some [documentation](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/Keystroke_Handling#Allowed_Control_Keys) you would come up with this :

```
<zk>
    <hbox>
        <intbox id="A"  onChanging="B.focus();" ctrlKeys="#bak" onCtrlKey="doSomething(D)" />
        <intbox id="B" onChanging="C.focus();"  ctrlKeys="#bak" onCtrlKey="doSomething(A)"  />
        <intbox id="C" onChanging="D.focus();" ctrlKeys="#bak" onCtrlKey="doSomething(B)" />
        <intbox id="D" onChanging="A.focus();" ctrlKeys="#bak" onCtrlKey="doSomething(C)"  />
        <zscript><![CDATA[
            public void doSomething(Component comp){
               comp.focus();
            }]]>
        </zscript>
    </hbox>
</zk>
```

However, I suggest just working with tab indexes and use shift + tab.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to implement a credit card input fields

```
<zk>
    <div  ctrlKeys="#bak" onCtrlKey="move(event)">
    <hlayout  >
        <intbox id="A" maxlength="4"  onChanging="next(event)"/>
        <intbox id="B"  maxlength="4" onChanging="next(event)"/>
        <intbox id="C" maxlength="4"  onChanging="next(event)"/>
        <intbox id="D" maxlength="4" onChanging="next(event)"/>
    </hlayout>
    </div>
    <zscript><![CDATA[
    public void move(KeyEvent e){
        Intbox intbox = (Intbox)event.getReference();
        if (intbox.getPreviousSibling() != null){
            intbox.getPreviousSibling().focus();
        }
    }
    public void next(InputEvent e){
        Intbox intbox = (Intbox)e.getTarget();
        if (e.getValue().toString().length() == intbox.getMaxlength()
            && intbox.getNextSibling() != null){
                intbox.getNextSibling().focus();

        }
    }
    ]]></zscript>
</zk>
```